# find the same key from the dictionary and place the subject in a new dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have 2 different responses from the server, with the same keys, which I converted to dictionaries:

```
dict1 = {'111': ['one', 1],
         'bla': ['blaa', blaa],
         '222': ['two', 2],
         'bla1: ['bla2', bla3],
         '333': ['three', 3],
}

dict2 = {'111': ['no matter what is here1'],
         'AAA': ['no matter what is here2'],
         '222': ['no matter what is here3'],
         'BBB': ['no matter what is here4'],
         '333': ['no matter what is here5'],
}
```

It doesn't matter to me what value is stored in dict2, I need for dict2 to find the same key in dict1 and put the complete item from dict1 into a new dict3 dictionary.

**The output should be like this:**

```
dict3 = {'111': ['one', 1],
         '222': ['two', 2],
         '333': ['three', 3],
```

Roughly speaking, the keys from dict2 are pointers, which items from dict1 to put into dict3

**It is important for me that the solution is NOT def ()**

Comment: `{key:dict1[key] for key in set(dict1.keys())&set(dict2.keys())}` works for you?

Comment: @Arjun Muraleedharan  yes.. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
dict1 = {'111': ['one', 1],
         'bla': ['blaa', 'blaa'],
         '222': ['two', 2],
         'bla1': ['bla2', 'bla3'],
         '333': ['three', 3],
}

dict2 = {'111': ['no matter what is here1'],
         'AAA': ['no matter what is here2'],
         '222': ['no matter what is here3'],
         'BBB': ['no matter what is here4'],
         '333': ['no matter what is here5'],
}


dict3 = {k: dict1.get(k) for k in dict2.keys() if k in dict1.keys()}

print(dict3)
# {'111': ['one', 1], '222': ['two', 2], '333': ['three', 3]}
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want the keys from `dict2` and the corresponding values (if exists) from `dict1`?

Something like this should work:

```
dict3 = {key:dict1.get(key) for key in dict2.keys() if dict1.get(key, None) is not None}
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the keys in dict2, check if that key is in dict1, and if it is put it in dict 3.

```
dict3 = {}

for k, _ in dict2.items():
    if k in dict1.keys():
        dict3[k] = dict1[k]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following here would generate `dict3` where it's all the values from `dict1`, that share a key from `dict2`.

```py
dict3 = {}

for key in dict2.keys():
    if key in dict1:
        dict3[key] = dict1[key]
```